# Toggle activity

Tags: java, android

Hy everybody,
I'm trying to make an app and I need to create second activity.

Now, I have:

1. `Activity1` with 3 `Button` with different ID. All button `onClick` switch `Activity1` to `Activity2`;
2. `Activity2` with `EditText` and `Spinner` and another `Button` (named `Button4`). `Spinner` to choose `Button1`, `Button2` or `Button3`. `EditText` for type number. `Button4` for back to `Activity1`;
3. I need that when I press `Button4` the app switches back to `Activity1` and set `height` of choose selected button (in `Spinner`) to number from `EditText`.

I know about `putExtra()`, `getIntent().GetExtras()`, etc.

Trouble is in setting height when I go back to `Activity1` from `Activity2`.

Simply say - I don't understand, what (of `onCreate()`, 
`onStart()`, `onResume()`, `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroy()`) i need to use :(

Help, please..

Comment: Are you getting the height from the `Activity2`? Maybe I've misunderstood and answered not what you needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need `startActivityForResult`. You can check [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) for the documentation.

The idea is: you start `Activity2` with this and wait for a result. When going back to `Activity1` a callback will deliver the result to you. Here the result should be the height selected.

I think there's no need for further explanation since the docs are pretty straightforward, but feel free to ask more help if some of it is not clear!